# How can I use next() inside passport.authenticate(...) in Express middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I have a simple passport setup with a `local` strategy for my login route. I'm not sure how to properly use the authentication function as a middleware though. Here is my Middleware that I call on the `/login` route before the controller:

```
exports.requireLogin = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    } else if (!user) {
      res.status(401).json(info.message);
    } else {
      req.login(user, (loginError) => {
        if (loginError) {
          console.log('error here');
          next(new Error('test'));
        } else {
          next();
        }
      });
    }
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

As you can see, the passport function is immediately invoked with the middleware parameters. That is what I found here on Stackoverflow as how to use next in that function.

Now that doesn't work for some reason. The error is not really handled as error. I checked this by making a none-error middleware as last possible endpoint in express and console-logged it out. I can see that it logs out the `error here` right before the line where the error is passed to `next` but it also logs out the check that the normal middleware is called after that.

As far as I know Express shouldn't call any normal middleware when you pass an error to next. Why doesn't this example work?